# Are polynomial rings regular local rings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

On the Wikipedia page of [Cohen–Macaulay rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Macaulay_ring) I found under 'examples' the following quote:

> Noetherian rings of the following types are Cohen–Macaulay.
>
> Any regular local ring.
> This leads to various examples of Cohen–Macaulay rings, such as the integers $\mathbb{Z}$, or a polynomial ring $K[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ over a field $K$, or a power series ring $K[[x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}]]$.

From this I gathered that $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is a regular local ring, whatever that means. This is bit suspicious, because $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is not local, but this type of misleading name is [actually quite common](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/red+herring+principle) in mathematics, e.g. a manifold with boundary is not a manifold, a multi-valued function is not a function etc. Let's see if we can understand the definition of [regular local ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_local_ring) by clicking the link.

There it says:

> In commutative algebra, a regular local ring is a Noetherian local ring having the property that the minimal number of generators of its maximal ideal is equal to its Krull dimension.

This leaves no doubt that in fact regular local rings are really local rings in the ordinary sense, and so polynomial rings are out. But then what is the article on Cohen–Macaulay rings trying to convey with above sentence?

And in particular, where do the polynomial rings fit in the following chain of increasingly nice classes of rings, discussed on Wikipedia:

Universally catenary rings $\supset$ Cohen–Macaulay rings $\supset$ Gorenstein rings $\supset$ complete intersection rings $\supset$ regular local rings

In fact my motivation for reading Wikipedia in the first place was to get a good grip on what classes of nice rings polynomial rings belong to. I wanted to learn some theorems about them, in particular on how to understand the dimension of algebraic subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n$ in terms of properties of the corresponding ideals, but many sources talk about much more general classes of rings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the title question first, of course not, polynomial rings are not local rings and therefore cannot be regular local rings.

---

What's going on here is that the verification that a noetherian ring is Cohen-Macaulay consists of checking some condition for all prime ideals. This is exactly what happens with checking that a noetherian ring is regular: we need to check that the localization at every prime is a regular local ring.

So if we have a ring that's regular, we know every localization at a prime is regular, and since a regular local ring is Cohen-Macaulay, we know the localization at every prime is Cohen-Macaulay, which means the ring is Cohen-Macaulay. The article is pointing out that this implies any regular ring is Cohen-Macaulay, and if one already knows some regular rings (like polynomial rings over fields or power series rings over fields) then one knows some Cohen-Macaulay rings as well.

---

Asking where polynomial rings fit in that sequence from Wikipedia is a little messy, since at some point they start requiring the adjective local - as we've discussed above, polynomial rings are not local. If one were to replace "regular local rings" with "regular rings", that's where the polynomial rings would live.

If you want to learn about the dimension of algebraic subsets of $\Bbb A^n$, crack open an introductory algebraic geometry book. Hartshorne or Vakil will probably do. (Resist the temptation to generalize to great lengths immediately without being able to do some calculations and get a grounding in the subject.)